# Any website that gather ongoing and upcoming strikes amongst airlines?

Tags: online-resources, airlines, industrial-action

A few weeks ago how to buy a flight ticket from Boston to Paris. I had to choose between Air France and Delta. Luckily a few friends of mine lives in Paris warned that Air France pilots had issued a notice of strike action and I should therefore better choose Delta, especially so since strikes in France often last [forever](http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/09/26/us-air-france-klm-strike-idUSKCN0HL0ZS20140926).

Is there any website that gather ongoing and upcoming strikes amongst airlines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not aware of a site targeted for strikes only, the best alternative to get fresh news from people in the aviation business is [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net). There is [a forum](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/) with thousands of people from all airlines and other aviation companies all around the world, they will keep you updated not only about strikes but about everything.