# How can I know of strikes that affect public transport in France?

Tags: public-transport, online-resources, france, event-based-effects, industrial-action

tl;dr: **Is there a resource that warns me of upcoming strikes that affect public transport in France**

Recently I was forced to change travel plans very last-minute upon learning of a railway strike. In the light of the current political situation in France and the upcoming football championship but asking completely in general:

1. Is there a resource where upcoming strikes that affect trains, buses, flights, local public transport in France are announced in advance?
2. Bonus question: If trains are affected, is there a way to find out which connections will be guaranteed?

Ideally I am looking for a resource similar to [the one described here for Italy.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/69026/32134)

Comment: The French tend to only strike in certain months. They are October, July, January, September, April, November, May, March, June, December, August, and February.

Comment: I've traveled to France three times in the last 10 years, and on those three trips my travel was disrupted by: A Paris metro strike, an SNCF strike, an air traffic controller strike, a baggage handlers strike and a labor action by truck drivers blocking some highways. That's **5** disruptions on just **3** trips, so even though people make jokes about the French propensity to strike (e.g., the joke by TheMathemagician) I think that it's basically true that they cannot be predicted and you should not make plans that require disruption-free travel in France. Nowadays when I travel in Europe I av

Comment: @TheMathemagician And even in those months only on days ending on -i (in French).

Comment: Most strikes occur on Thursdays. Unless workers are really angry in which case they'll just strike whenever.

Comment: @ptityeti These days one can't even rely on the French any more. They wouldn't let my airplane land on a dimanche. Had to spend 3 long, dreadful days with friends in a airline-paid hotel in Copenhagen until I got another flight home. Best strike ever ;)

Comment: The main idea for a strike is to make it so inconvenient so that there would be as much people affected as possible thus creating a news-worsy story. Imagine a strike, that everyone knows about and everyone can easily avoid. Would anyone care about it? Would people going on strike achieve their goals if no one cares? Most probably no. Which leads to a conclusion that most probably you will not find a relevant information about strikes.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I'm sorry but that's nonsense. Knowing about a strike doesn't make it easy or necessarily even possible to avoid. For example, a public transport strike in, say, London or Paris causes huge amounts of disruption and would still be hugely disruptive even if it was announced weeks in advance. People care deeply when they can't get to work.

Comment: I remember my first visit to a big French factory site. To get to the entrance gate from the car park, we walked across a football-pitch-sized area paved with concrete, with some strange looking low concrete podiums around the edges. Somebody asked our hosts what it was. The answer: "Oh, that's where we hold our industrial disputes". I quite like the notion of a factory plan that includes an officially designated area purpose-built for rioting!

Comment: @SalvadorDali: you got a point. School directors have been on administrative strike (not transmitting statistics to their Ministry but assuming their duties to pupils) for a long time (probably still on strike right now) but no one cares.

Comment: @DavidRicherby can't agree with you. Knowing that a subway will not be available in two weeks for 3 days is not the same as coming, waiting, not being able to ride and only then figuring out that it is not working. Surely you still can't use it, but at least in the first place you are prepared and can do something to mitigate the problem. Being prepared is always better than being clueless.

Comment: @SalvadorDali younger, there was a pulic transit strike in my city. We all knew in advance. Lasted for like 2 weeks. Had to walk to and from school. Even if you know,some people WILL be inconvenienced. Might be better, but better than bad != good.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Um. If the subway is on strike, the stations are closed. You aren't going to be standing on the platform thinking, "Gee, why are we all waiting so long for a train today?" There are also minimum notice periods, at least in the UK, so you'd know at least a day or two in advance, assuming you were paying attention to the news.

Comment: French here. I'd like to get an answer to this question too :). More seriously : it depends on were you want to go. For example, in Toulouse you'll have to go to www.tisseo.fr to have information on how strikes affect the local buses and metros.

Comment: SalvadorDali's point is very correct; strikes do aim at causing problems to as many people as possible, and they are usually announced with very short notice if any at all mainly for that purpose. It's as obvious as irrelevant that if they are announced longer before they would still inconvenience many people, because that would be much less people inconvenienced anyway.

Comment: FYI [Any website that gather ongoing and upcoming strikes amongst airlines?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/36900/1810)

Comment: @SantiBailors It makes some sense (as do David's points) but it's all kind of moot as public sector strikes in France are **not** “usually announced with very short notice”, that's just a fact. There is a legal delay of 5 days that's seldom disregarded (there are some examples, say when workers walk out after a colleague has been attacked but it's not common) and the reality is that they really announced in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This website:

http://www.cestlagreve.fr/

has information on most of the strikes. With a little bit of google translate, you can search by tag for the trains or other types of transport. And as the commenter below pointed out, there is even an app.

If you are worried about the trains in Paris, for example, search by "RATP", "SNCF", or "Paris". For the cross-country train system, type "TGV".

In my experience, Uber is alive and well during a strike, even in the suburbs.

Comment: That's a great resource! There even exists an app.

Comment: I love that domain name :-)

Answer (score 12):

*Source: French, 32 years of living in France.*

First of all, while we French have a reputation for going on strikes often, it is actually quite disproportionate. For example, I have myself not participated to a single strike, ever, and few of my friends have. I have, however, experienced a few :)

The strikes are more frequent in certain domains of activities, where the unions are most active. They are most frequent among government employees (notably in the Education sector) and current and former national/regional companies (notably in the SNCF).

With that out of the way, you have to understand that the goal of strikes is to pressure higher-ups in order to weigh on decisions (past or coming), and the pressure is generally applied by creating discomfort among the users/clients.

The result is that strikes are generally not announced too long in advance so that said users/clients do not have the time to take appropriate counter-measures and do experience the discomfort (and thus complain). The present situation is actually somewhat of a counter-example, with its long-ranging announces.

However, while the intention of strike has to be announced in advance (in public services), no single individual has to declare its own intention until the last moment. Though generally people express their own intent informally (to colleagues), they are allowed to change their mind one way or another (unless requisitioned, in some specific sectors such as security or health).

This individual freedom makes it very difficult to work out the exact impact of a strike in advance. Companies and other media agencies attempt to estimate it by polling, and thus obtain an estimated ratio of people on strikes, but (1) this is an estimate and (2) it does not specify exactly who will be available where and when.

For the case of primary schools, where classes start around 9am, it is fairly easy to take a roll-call at 9am and see which teachers made it and which sent a letter/mail informing they are on strike. Though of course, by this time the children are there already and those at work have to make do.

For other cases, though, where the individual schedules of employees do not line up on such a neat boundary, the impact of the strike is discovered throughout the day: each time an employee shows up, or let the employer knows she is on strike.

Thus, for Air Traffic Control or the SNCF, where employees show up a few at a time (not 9-to-5 jobs), the impact is assessed little by little, and flights/trains cancelled, delayed, rerouted, ... to the best of the ability of the management and present workers.

This means that even if you *know* there is a strike a given day, you can only predict it will be a difficult day for some people, but now who they are and how difficult it will be for them... if you need to travel on such a day, arm yourself with patience, and a few luck charms.

Comment: Good information!

Comment: It's only in the public service that strikes have to be announced in advance (*préavis*). Private sector workers can walk out at the drop of a hat.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately I think  there is no governemental website listing all planned strikes.

Most of the time, we know upcoming strikes just a few days ahead with the news (TV, web, etc).

So your best bet is to go directly to the public transport websites, generally they have to inform users about strikes, or even call them directly.

For your second question, the [trafic info](http://www.sncf.com/fr/horaires-info-trafic) website of the SNCF allows you to search for specific journeys to see if they will be maintained or not.

Comment: +1 but waiting to accept for a bit longer in case someone comes around or decides to build such a website ;)

Comment: I somehow doubt that a website would be built if it doesn't already exist ;)

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be no dedicated site displaying French Strikes, but the below information may be useful.

> Strikes (les grèves) in France affect public transport services fairly often. Here are some useful sites for up-to-the-minute information during France's industrial disputes and manifestations.

[Click here to view the useful links - there are too many to list in this answer](https://www.angloinfo.com/france/how-to/page/france-transport-public-transport-strikes#sthash.1wTDstwF.dpuf)

The French & Worldwide Media will update you on strike, [this example tells you of current and soon upcoming strikes](http://www.thelocal.fr/20160525/heres-how-youll-be-affected-by-frances-upcoming-strikes)

The French are often striking, so try and be aware...

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest Twitter as a source for this kind of information - anything that will be significant (not very small region but the whole country) will be easy to find there.  https://twitter.com/search?q=france+strike for example will find a fair number of articles about the SNCF strike that you're referring to, as well as some recent past strikes.